# How to order by using two columns in my sql?

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to create the SMS messaging you see on android phones.

In my MySQL database, I have a table which is used to keep track of messaging which is like SMS from a phone.

The table is

```
id                  (the message id)
from_member_id      (the id of the member who sent this message)
to_member_id        (the id of the member who the message was sent to)
date sent           (the date it was sent)
active              (if this message is deleted or active)
text                (the text)
```

When a user logs in, they need to download all the messages, that either they sent or got sent to.

I can create a sql statement that basically says "give me all the records that my id equals the from or to id" but what I also want to do is sort it in a way that its easy to process when displaying the text on my android app.

Basically I want to sort it so that its like ordered so that the id that's not you (which will either be the `from` or `to`) is what its ordered by. Plus it should be ordered by date or what was most recently sent or received.

So for example, if my ID is 5, then I want to receive the data like

```
From To Date
5     6 july 28
6     5 july 7
6     5 july 7

5     2 july 26
5     2 july 26
2     5 july 26
```

So it also gets ordered by date where the date record it uses for comparison would be the most recent of each group.

I'm not sure if I explained it right, so let me know if you need me to be more specific.

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] to include your SQL. It's hard to tell you how to make it work the way you want when you don't show us what you're doing now that isn't working for you.

Comment: *so that the id that's not you (which will either be the from or to) is what its ordered by* - In what sense? Should other people be first in the results, last? Should date matter more than anything else? Usually you just go `ORDER BY column_a ASC, column_b DESC`.

Comment: Basically, the rows need to be ordered in a special way, if I use order by, then I have to choose a column, but what if I want to order by the value thats not your id, that is the part I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in essence you are trying to group by "conversation target" and then by date.

I would think what you might need is a case statement to populate an artificial field that you can order by like this:

```
SELECT
  from_member_id,
  to_member_id,
  (CASE WHEN from_member_id = ? THEN to_member_id ELSE from_member_id END CASE) AS conversation_member_id,
  date_sent
FROM table
WHERE from_member_id = ?
OR to_member_id = ?
ORDER BY conversation_member_id DESC, date_sent DESC
```

Here of course `?` is the id you are querying on.

Comment: I noticed something, when you order by the 'other' id, then by date, then for each section of same 'other' id's, the dates will be ordered there in that section. But how do I order it by date relative to all the sections?

Comment: Ah yes I didn't read that initial requirement from your question right. That makes things more complex.  I would likely create a subquery to determine max date by conversation_member_id and then join the result of that subquery to the query shown with an additional order by for that max column.  Honestly if you have that need though, I would strongly recommend thinking about your DB schema such that you have a separate "conversation" table which could always be updated with the latest timestamp. Without this, your query will be extremely inefficient.

Comment: What if I dont do that last complex ordering here in mysql, but I do that in java code when the phone gets the data in my android app?

Comment: Even my initial query is not optimized and won't be able to take full advantage of indexes, as you are performing a sort on a calculated field.  I would really strongly consider a schema change regardless. My guess is that down the line, you may not want to load all this data into the application at one time (for memory reasons) in which case you may want to be able to do things like download all message id's to/from a certain contact and then asynchronously load individual messages based on display needs.

Comment: ... Trying to do that against a backend which can't separate the concepts of conversations from that of messages easily could be architecturally limiting.

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY IF(`from`=yourid, `to`, `from`) DESC, date asc ;
```

This shoudl solve your problem. You can additionally add order by date also

Comment: Edited my answer with date also

Comment: Date can be asc or desc based on your requirement

Comment: See my comment above for Mike Brant answer.